# How are subscripts and superscripts read in Spanish?

Tags: matemáticas

How should I pronounce subscripts and superscripts when read in Spanish mathematics?  For example, how should I say "A<sub>1</sub>" and "A<sup>1</sup>"?

Comment: If not mathematical symbols, is read as if they were ordinary signs: _a uno_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aparte de *súper*, el superíndice también se puede leer como *supra*: x<sup>1</sup> se leería como

> equis supra uno.

---

Hay que notar que no estamos hablando de exponentes en una potencia ni de orden de una derivada. Eso se escribe como un superíndice pero, así como la función del superíndice es distinguir una variable de otra, el exponente y el orden de una derivada implican una operación sobre la variable, y por eso tienen una lectura relacionada con su función y no con su escritura (x elevado a 1; (primera) derivada de x; derivada 1-ésima de x...) y los superíndices leen como superíndices (*super*/*supra*), no como exponentes.

---

Añado que, **en la práctica**, aunque técnicamente se haya de leer *sub*, *súper*/*supra*, **muchas veces se omite esto**.

Si por ejemplo tienes un vector x=(x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>), si no hay confusión con superíndices, las componentes se leen:

> equis uno, equis dos, ..., equis ene.

Lo mismo sería para superíndices, si no hay uso simultáneo de subíndices y por tanto confusión.

Para matrices, donde las notaciones más usales son:

> A=(a<sub>i</sub><sup>j</sup>),
>   A=(a<sub>i</sub><sub>j</sub>),

en la práctica (nuevamente si no hay confusión) tranquilamente se lee

> a i jota.

---

También hay que remarcar que **no todos los subíndices se leen como tal**. Por ejemplo, si X es un espacio topológico con la topología asociada τ<sub>X</sub>, a τ<sub>X</sub> se la leerá como *la topología de equis*. Otro ejemplo: la norma euclídea, normalmente escrita || · ||<sub>2</sub>, donde

> ||x||<sub>2</sub>

se lee como

> norma euclídea de equis.

---

Los casos de las potencias o, como el ejemplo que ofrece @guifa, del logaritmo, son algo diferentes del caso común, pues tienen un concepto matemático implícito, afectan con algún tipo de operación matemática a la variable sobre la que están. No son para distinguir, simplemente, un elemento de otro o hacer una enumeración de variables -eso lo hacen los subíndices y superíndices. Las derivadas, las potencias, los logaritmos, los límites...  Todo eso se corresponde con un concepto matemático determinado y se lee en correspondencia a ello.

- La función logaritmo. Cuando no es el *neperiano*, debemos indicar la base de esta manera:

  > log<sub>a</sub>x se lee «logaritmo en base a de equis».
  >   log<sub>10</sub>x se lee «logaritmo en base diez de equis».
- Los límites:

  > lím<sub>x→a</sub>f(x)
  >   se lee
  >   «el límite cuando equis tiende a a de efe de equis».

Comment: No recuerdo haber oído *supra* para los superíndices, pero tiene sentido. Y, desde luego, cuando no hay riesgo de confusión, es habitual eliminar la mención a *sub*, *super* o lo que sea. Creo que esta respuesta es la más completa.

Answer (score 5):

Reading a [guide for teachers](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&sqi=2&ved=0CD0QFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rmm.cl%2Fusuarios%2Fcjara%2Fdoc%2F200802171451400.notacionmatematica.doc&ei=QqWPVPiSMsSqggSz_YKABQ&usg=AFQjCNG31qgRLPPIq-Eh3GG37ygvzVBueg&sig2=TQ_HU4Hz8N1o0uel674T8Q), it says superscripts should be read as *elevado a X*,   If the subscript is for bases, then you'd read it as *en base X*, otherwise (for sets and series), it's read as *sub X*

But, I just asked a friend who is a math professor from Argentina, though he's lived in the US for a while.  He confirmed the reading of *A<sub>1</sub>* as *a sub uno*.  But he said that *A<sup>1</sup>* would be read as *a a la una* such that for him something like *Y<sup>x-1</sup>* would be *ye a la equis menos uno*.

Answer (score 3):

A subscript is almost always read *sub*. As for superscripts, if it is a power, it is read *elevado a la* or just *a la*; but, if it is a real superscript (not the exponent of a power), it is read *super*.

Thus, [image] would read *a super i sub jota*.

Some examples of this use can be found in [this document](http://www.juntadeandalucia.es/averroes/caidv/interedvisual/ftp/cmu_88_98.doc).

Comment: Debí haber preguntado a mi amigo eso de los superscriptos en el caso de no ser potencias.  Gracias.

Comment: While I do agree with thia answer, I think some source would be nice

Comment: @clinch I have no sources, I just studied maths back in the time. But I will look for some.